# NVIDIA Graphics Card Issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

Apparently Ubuntu and NVIDIA graphics cards don't get along. This is because I have received a multitude of issues while trying to install and use my NVIDIA GTX 750Ti graphics card.

#### ISSUE 1:

I cannot get the monitor plugged into my graphics card, to display anything that looks like a GUI. This has lead me to attempt to install a graphics driver, which has lead to several other problems.

#### ISSUE 2:

Every time I attempt to install a driver, it has either done nothing (I still can't plug my monitor into the graphics card) or it has broken my install to the point where I have to reinstall Ubuntu from a bootable USB

#### Note:

A terminal installation is preferred, because my MadCatz gaming mouse doesn't work correctly, and every time I fix it, something deletes/renames/clears the `xorg.conf` in X11.

Also, the way I have been able to see Ubuntu, is using a second monitor that is plugged into the motherboard, and by switching the main monitor between the graphics card and the motherboard

Comment: How are you installing the driver (official `apt` package, PPA `apt` package, installation script from NVIDIA)?

Comment: @KarlRichter I think I've tried them all, but I distinctly remember using PPA and the installation script

Comment: Ubuntu version(s)? NVIDIA driver versions? PPA URL? A description of what you see if preferred over a description what you don't see ("anything that looks like a GUI"). What does `sudo dkms autoinstall` show?

Comment: @KarlRichter Ubuntu Version: 12.04, NVIDIA Driver Version: 346, PPA URL: No idea, I just followed a tutorial, `sudo dkms autoinstall`: I can check but I'd need to boot Ubuntu, Description: Depends on the situation, on my most recent attempt at installing NVIDIA, all the windows were big black boxes which I couldn't move... (continued to new comment)

Comment: @KarlRichter When I boot with the monitor plugged into the graphics card, I get the BIOS screen, the GRUB window, then a black screen. If after that I plug the monitor into the motherboard, I get the normal Ubuntu loading screen (if a NVIDIA installation didn't screw it up)

Comment: @KarlRichter It might be because I'm not in Ubuntu but in the terminal after Ubuntu telling me I'm in low graphics mode, but `sudo dkms autoinstall` does nothing

Comment: This is all relevant to your question. Please edit it in order to get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're suffering from the [xorg bug 1405696](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1405696) of the NVIDIA driver version 346. You can watch the status of the bug until it changes to `Fix committed` to use 346. Meanwhile you should stick with 340 by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`. In your case you might be obliged to type it blindly to try to install the driver in a `chroot`. The PPA versions are experimental and it might happen that such dramatic issues occur.

Comment: When I try `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340` I get the error: `unable to locate the package nvidia-340`

Comment: Actually, don't worry I added a ppa to download it